# I’m getting a ‘you need to load the kernel first’ error and boot/grub might be empty

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I used to be able to boot Ubuntu from my SSD drive on a duel boot machine but now it says “you need to load the kernel first”.

I have tried to set the boot drive.
I found the partition with lost+found/ boot/ swapfile etc/ media/ var/ … and so on. I believe this is my partition for boot/grub/ by what I’ve read online.

My problem might be that there is nothing in this path.
[The Documentation says](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#Search_.26_Set) /boot/grub should contain “ grub.cfg and many *.mod files. If looking for a specific file, include the name in the search to limit the number of returns”.
But there is nothing in this path but a file named grubenv.

Also, I don’t know what this disk is named. In grub it is (hd2,gpt4) and I can get the UUID number, but isn’t there another name that is something like /dev/hd1? Do I not need this to set the kernel if I ever find it?

I’m using Ubuntu 20.04
5.11.0-41 generic

Answer (score 1):

My MoBo is a B450-A pro max. It has two options to change the UEFI. One in the boot menu and one in the Windows menu under advanced options. I changed from CSM to UEFI in the Windows option and I’m duel booting again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It can be useful for other users :-)